# Why is my XMLHttpRequest() objects' status 0?

Tags: javascript

This code works and status is 200 when my url is 'localhost:8888/signin.html?#'. However when its 'localhost:8888/signin.html'the status is 0.

what is the '?#' that was being added in the url? would making the post request in some other way help?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">



  function myFunction2(){
    //grab user entered values for posting to API
    uid=document.getElementById('username').value;
    pass=document.getElementById('password').value;

    //Generate url for Post request
    var url='http://127.0.0.1:5000/login/'+uid+'/'+pass

   
   //making Post request to API
   const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();  
   xhr.open("POST", url);  
   xhr.send(null); 

  
    xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
       window.alert(xhr.readyState);
       window.alert(xhr.status);
      if(xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200){

        if(xhr.responseText){
           const data = xhr.responseText; //json returned by post request
          window.alert("fefed");
            myFunction3(data); 
           
        }
      }
    }
  }


 function myFunction3(data){
    
        if(datas == "login failed"){
          window.alert(datas);
          localStorage.setItem("user",uid);
          console.log(localStorage.getItem("user"));
          window.alert(localStorage.getItem("user"));
        }
     
        
  }


</script>
```

Comment: Nobody can answer this without knowing how your server process the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, we need to know how the server processes the request.  However, I do see one glaring omission from your code.  You need to add

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

between your open and send calls if you are using POST.  In fact, you should be using that for all requests anyways.  The ? in your URL is to separate the URL from parameters and is part of the WWW specification.  Anything after ? is considered data and is not part of the URL.  Additionally, if you are using the ? mechanism, then you should be using the GET method instead.